# Bounty and rep dissapeared

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

Question: [Creating own implementation of Boost::Archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921151/creating-own-implementation-of-boostarchive)

I added bounty to it.

No answer recieved.

I applied bounty to my own answer (to get 50 rep back).

Bounty dissapeared, I didn't recieve 50 rep back.

---

https://stackoverflow.com/reputation shows line "8 3921151 (-50)" and no "(+50)" line.

Answer (score 5):

Accepting your own answer does not give the bounty, I'm afraid. This is by-design; otherwise bounty would always be *essentially* free - just offer a bounty, get some nice answers, then accept your own answer to get the points back.

Comment: But I didn't recieve ANY answers at all. So I lost 50 rep for nothing.

Comment: It is regrettable that there werent answers, I agree; but that doesn't change the way bounty works. I wish I knew the answer for your SO question.